# Adjust images with different dimensions side by side with css in Jupyter

Tags: html, css, image, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to put two images side-by-side in a markdown cell in Jupyter. But the two images have different dimensions and I can't get them to be exactly the same size.

My goal is that the images have the same proportions regardless of their size. In the image that I put here you can see that the "fig 2" lacks height to match in size with the "fig 1".

![Images side by side][(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhplT.jpg)

Below I put the CSS and HTML code that I have used to put images side by side.

Code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  object-fit: fill;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
}


}

/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <a id="fig1" href="./../../Images/r-project.png">
    <img src="https://imgur.com/opaKw3b" alt="R-Proyect" style="width:100px height:100px"/>
    </a>
  <figcaption>Fig 1</figcaption>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <a id="fig2" href="./../../Images/cran.png">
    <img src="https://imgur.com/iYnTl8H" alt="CRAN" style="width:50% height:100px">
    </a>
  <figcaption>Fig 2</figcaption>
</div>
```

I hope you can help me with that little problem. Thanks.

Comment: The image may be of different height too ? What do you want in the remaining portion ?

Comment: @XxSTREKxX I just want them to have the same width and height and be shown side by side

Comment: You want the image division to elongate if the height doesnt match ? and fig 1 and fig 2 to appear at the same height ? is that it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If your images are of different height and width and you want the image to elongate its height you need to mention the height of the image.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
}

img{
height:400px;
}

}

/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <a id="fig1" href="./../../Images/r-project.png">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="R-Proyect" />
    </a>
  <figcaption>Fig 1</figcaption>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <a id="fig2" href="./../../Images/cran.png">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/f00/f0f" alt="CRAN">
    </a>
  <figcaption>Fig 2</figcaption>
</div>
```

2. If you do not want the image to elongate but the text at the bottom to be at the right space try this

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.imgholder {
  height: 400px;
  width:100%;
  background-size:cover 50% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dummyimage.com/200x400/2222e6/fff)" class="imgholder">
    </div>
    <p>Fig1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dummyimage.com/300x200/122666/fff)" class="imgholder">
    </div>
    <p>Fig2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for